# How can I get the player that opens a crafting table in a Fabric mod?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

How can I get the player that opens a crafting table in a Fabric mod?

My current code to get inventory title/type

```java
@Mixin(HandledScreens.class)
public class FastCraftMixin {
    @Inject(at = @At("HEAD"), method = "open")
    private static <T extends ScreenHandler> void open(ScreenHandlerType<T> type, MinecraftClient client, int id, Text title, CallbackInfo ci) {
        System.out.println(title.toString());
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one `MinecraftClient` object and that class only exists on the client. Only one player can be playing on a client. If you're writing a function that has a `MinecraftClient` parameter then you know the player is ***the*** player. You could get it with `client.player` (as already mentioned) but you should also be aware that on clients, you can also use `MinecraftClient.getInstance().player` since there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `client` object to get player.

You can use [`client.player`](https://maven.fabricmc.net/docs/yarn-1.16.4+build.1/net/minecraft/client/MinecraftClient.html#player).

In some version, it's `mcPlayer` object.